# A Question About Python Scripting Using Row.Prop

Tags: python, scripting

I'm newbie to Blender Python Scripting, and I have tried to follow the video tutorial posted in [this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hF-cyH8Z7WQ&list=PLFtLHTf5bnym_wk4DcYIMq1DkjqB7kDb-&index=2)(about 11::44 in timeline). But I was caught by a trouble about using the row.prop() function:
[image]
It seems that scripting system idenfied the Variable "context.obeject" as a 'None' type and so that have thrown such an error, although I only just followed this tutorial step by step. I do want to know how to solve it. Thanks for your help!
By the way, my blender version is 3.1.2, and it seems the version of blender in this tutorial is 2.8.Maybe that's why the error occurs?

Comment: When the offending line is executed, does any object exist? More specifically, is any object active? If there isn't, `context.object` cannot possibly be anything but `None`. You say you followed the tutorial step by step, but in the tutorial under the timestamp given, we can see a cube, and in your case we can't.

Comment: I suggest using a guard clause. either `try: row.prop(context.object, "scale") except TypeError: row.label(text="Select an object")` or `if context.object: row.prop(context.object, "scale") else: row.label(text="Select an object")`

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Hi, I just tried to run the absolutely same script in the blender 3.6 and it worked. As you said, the error may be caused by no active object existing; however, even in this case the script still worked if it runs in the blender 3.6 but not in 3.1. It seems there is any bug in 3.1?